# flexunit addAsync chaining

Tags: actionscript-3, flexunit

For some reason, addAsync chaining in a flexunit test as described in [this article](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showDetails&postId=6882&productId=2&loc=en_US) utterly fails to work when I try to do it.

```
public function testWhatever():void {
    var cont:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    cont.addEventListener("continue", addAsync(verifyFirst, 1000));
    cont.dispatchEvent(new Event("continue"));
}

private function verifyFirst(e:Event):void {
    var cont:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    cont.addEventListener("continue", addAsync(verifySecond, 1000));
    cont.dispatchEvent(new Event("continue"));
}

private function verifySecond(e:Event):void {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

If I run this test, verifyFirst gets called but verifySecond does not. I'm assuming this is a bug in flexunit ... is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more research and found that this is indeed a bug in flexunit, which looks to be [fixed](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FXU-19) in the next release. The workaround I found was to instead use `Application.application.callLater` to dispatch the second event.

```
private function verifyFirst(e:Event):void {
    var cont:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    cont.addEventListener("continue", addAsync(verifySecond, 1000));
    Application.application.callLater(cont.dispatchEvent,
       [new Event("continue")]);
}
```

This question was inspired by an attempt to inspect the state of an object after everything in Flash's event queue had been processed. I discovered a simpler way to accomplish this without messing with `EventDispatcher`s.

Make the following call the end of the first part of the test when you want the event queue to be processed.

`Application.application.callLater(addAsync(phaseTwo, 1000, [`*args...*`]), [null]);`

With the `phaseTwo` function having the following signature.

`private function phaseTwo(e:Event, args:Array):void`

`e` will be passed a `null` object. This is necessary to be compatible with `addAsync`.